# How to put the given context-free grammar into Chomsky Normal Form?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, normal-forms

I have questions about how to put the grammar below in CNF - Chomsky Normal Form:

S ->aAa | bBb | ВВ;

A -> C;

B -> S | A;

C -> S | ε;

I did it like this:

1. I eliminated empty productions:

S ->aAa | aa | bBb | bb| ВВ;

A -> C;

B -> S | A;

C -> S;

2. I eliminated unit productions:

S ->aAa | aa | bBb | bb | ВВ;

A -> aAa | aa | bBb | bb | ВВ;

B -> Aa | aa | bBb | bb | ВВ;

C -> Aa | aa | bBb | bb | ВВ;

3. I eliminated the useless variables (C), but it only becomes inaccessible after removing the unitary production of A ->C). Can anyone help me and tell me if this is right?

Answer (score 0):

It is the case that $C$ becomes inaccessible, but your grammar isn't in normal form (yet).
Rules like $S \to aAa$ or $S \to bb$ aren't allowed in [CNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form).

Also your grammar isn't equal to the original, since you forgot that $S$ is nullable when removing the $\varepsilon$ production (e.g. you could derive $S \Rightarrow BB \Rightarrow^* AA \Rightarrow^* CC \Rightarrow^* \varepsilon$ which isn't possible in your last grammar).

When bringing a grammar in CNF it's often a good idea to remove all $A \to B$ transitions first, and then remove the $\varepsilon$ transitions.
So first start off by adding a new start variable $S'$

$$S \to S'$$
$$S' \to aAa | bBb | BB$$
$$A \to C$$
$$B \to S' | A$$
$$C \to S' | \varepsilon$$

then remove the $A \to C$ and $B \to A$ transition

$$S \to S'$$
$$S' \to aAa | bBb | BB$$
$$A \to S' | \varepsilon$$
$$B \to S' | \varepsilon$$

$C$ is now inaccessible, so we'll ignore it. Remove $A \to S'$ and $B \to S'$

$$S \to S'$$
$$S' \to aAa | aS'a | bBb | bS'b | BB | S'B | BS' | S'S'$$
$$A \to \varepsilon$$
$$B \to \varepsilon$$

remove the $\varepsilon$ transitions

$$S \to S' | \varepsilon$$
$$S' \to aa | aS'a | bb | bS'b | S' | S'S' | \varepsilon$$

remove $S' \to \varepsilon$ and $S' \to S'$

$$S \to S' | \varepsilon$$
$$S' \to aa | aS'a | bb | bS'b | S'S'.$$

This can now be brought into CNF

$$S \to S' | \varepsilon$$
$$S' \to AA | AX | BB | BY | S'S'$$
$$A \to a$$
$$X \to S'A$$
$$B \to B$$
$$Y \to S'B$$

as you should verify :]